# Keyword auto-complete broken: "Server method 'ValidateTerms' failed"

Tags: managed-metadata, term-store

**Managed metadata keyword auto-completion** (when you type the start of a taxonomy keyword, it auto-completes the rest) **works on one of my sites but not the other**.

**On the non-working server, there is a JavaScript error "Server method 'ValidateTerms' failed".**

As far as I can see, the set-up (features, rights etc) is identical. What could be the problem?

Only the auto-completion is broken - everything else works. If I type a new keyword, it ends up in "System" like normal.

Answer (score 3):

**The problem is that the SharePoint site is running on `http://mysite` internally, but is exposed as `https://mysite` using Microsoft Forefront**.

This breaks the `ValidateTerms` AJAX method call, because the call is made to http`://mysite` while surfing on `https://mysite`, which **violates the same-origin policy** of `XMLHttpRequest` calls.

So the JSON AJAX call to `ValidateTerms` ends up as an `OPTIONS` call to `ValidateTerms`, which returns a 302 to the same URL, but the SharePoint client gets confused and interprets this is as "server method failed".

I don't know if Forefront is configured correctly or not, but the rest of SharePoint works, so I'm guessing there's a special case here.

Tricky stuff!